httpd rewrite causing 404 loop
I have taken over an older project that is using Toro to serve routes in a PHP project, and I am having a hard time understanding exactly what it's doing.  I believe my issue is in my apache mod rewrite, but I cannot understand what this mod rewrite is doing as it came from the previous project owner and I am not well-versed in rewrites.
The project is using the following rewrite rules in httpd.conf.  Can someone explain to me what these statements are doing?
<Directory "c:/xampp/htdocs">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    #
    # REWRITES
    #
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteBase /project/
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
      RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php/$1 [L]
      
    </IfModule>

</Directory>

While developing on localhost, I am getting 404 errors when I load any page
if I go to: localhost/project/login
With these first two files:

login - loads 200 - Request URL : http://localhost/project/login
jqueryui.css - 404 - Request URL : http://localhost/web/vendors/jquery-ui/jquery.css

This request SHOULD be  ...localhost/project/web/vendors/...





add
<base href="http://localhost/project/" > in <head> section </head> - on server use https://real_domain.com/

The rewrite setup basically rewrites all requests that do not map onto an existing file or folder, to the index.php. Static assets should not be affected by that, because they do of course exist as files. But with the path for yours apparently being wrong, they should be rewritten to the index.php - if that is the case, then the 404 response would have to have been created by the index.php itself, not the web server. That's probably the first thing you should figure out here - if that 404 comes from the webserver itself, or the script.

The apache http server's rewrite module offers a feature called RewriteLogging. If you enable it (see the documentation for that) you get a detailed insight into what exactly is going on inside your rewriting engine. On a step by step base you can follow the processing.
